# Copy Network files listed in .txt to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3

I have a txt file with a list of files (with full network path) that I need to copy to an AWS S3 bucket.

Within the network I use this:

```
$files = get-content "C:\Users\Jesse\Desktop\Source Files.txt"

foreach($file in $files){
   copy-item $file -dest "\\domain\Fileshare\department\folder\"}
```

I need something equivalent to read the txt file and then copy the listed item from its path listed in the text file to the S3 bucket with folder hierarchy in tact.

I have been able to copy a single file via:

```
$AKey   = 'AccessKeyID'
$SKey   = 'SecretKeyID'
$region = 'us-west-2'

Initialize-AWSDefaultConfiguration -AccessKey $AKey -SecretKey $SKey -Region $region
 
Write-S3Object -BucketName BucketName/PDF -File \\Server\Archive\Folder\STATE\FIFEWA\Item.pdf
```

However, this only copies one file, need powershell to reference the txt document with all the files listed and copy with all their respective folders.

Comment: You can use the AWS Tools for Powershell [Write-S3Object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Write-S3Object.html) or you can use the AWSCLI.

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).